# How can I optimize my program?

Tags: c++, c, optimization

I wrote program which realises this formula:

Pi = 1/n * summ( 4 / ( 1 + ((i-0.5) /n)^2)

Program code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
using namespace std;

const long double PI = double(M_PI);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    typedef struct timeval tm;
    tm start, end;
    int  timer = 0;
    int n;

    if (argc == 2) n = atoi(argv[1]);
    else n = 8000;

    long double pi1 = 0;
    gettimeofday ( &start, NULL );

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        pi1 += 4 / ( 1 + (i-0.5) * (i-0.5) / (n*n) );
    }

    pi1/=n;
    gettimeofday ( &end, NULL );
    timer = ( end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec ); 
    long double delta = pi1 - PI;
    printf("pi = %.12Lf\n",pi1);
    printf("delta = %.12Lf\n", delta);

    cout << "time = " << timer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How to present it in an optimal way? when there will be less floating-point operations in this part:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            pi1 += 4 / ( 1 + (i-0.5) * (i-0.5) / (n*n) );
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean "less operations" - lines of code or instructions once built?

Comment: Sergey, does your spacebar not work?

Comment: why combine `printf` and `cout`

Comment: Nim, I mean instructions

Comment: Do you want to calculate PI or is this question about optimization? Calculating pi (or other series functions) with IEEE floating point is an entire science by itself.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read this excellent document:

[Software Optimization Guide for AMD64 Processors](http://j.mp/GATHdw)

Which is also great when you do not have an AMD processor.

But if I were you, I would replace the whole calculation loop with just

```
pi1 = M_PI;
```

Which will probably be the fastest... If you are actually interested in a faster algorithm for Pi calculations, look at the Wikipedia article: [Category:Pi algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aPi_algorithms)

If you just want to microoptimize your code, read the above mentioned software optimization guide.

Answer (score 3):

one idea will be:

```
double nn = n*n;
for(double i = 0.5; i < n; i += 1) {
    pi1 += 4 / ( 1 + i * i / nn );
}
```

but you need to test if it is any difference with current code.

Answer (score 2):

Examples of simple optimization:

- compute `double one_per_n = 1/n;` outside the `for` loop reducing the cost of dividing by `n`on each iteration
- compute `double j = (i-0.5) * one_per_n` inside the loop
- `pi1 += 4 / (1 + j*j);`

This should be faster and also avoid the integer overflow you have for greater values of `n`. For even more optimized code you will have to look at the generated code and use a profiler to make appropriate changes. The optimized code this way might behave differently on machines with a different CPU or cache.... Avoiding divisions is something that is always good to do to save computation time.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>

#ifndef M_PI //M_PI is non standard make you sure catch this case
    #define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif

typdef long double float_t;
const float_t PI = double(M_PI);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = argc == 2 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 8000;
    float_t pi1=0.0;
    //if you can using auto here is a no brainer
    std::chrono::time_point start   
          =std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    unsigned n2=n*n;
    for(unsigned i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        pi1 += 4.0 / ( 1.0 + (i-0.5) * (i-0.5) / n2 );
    }
    pi1/=n;
    std::chrono::duration<double> time
         =std::chrono::system_clock::now()-start;

    float_t delta = pi1 - PI;

    std::cout << "pi = " << std::setprecision(12) << pi1
              << "delta = " << std::setprecision(12) << delta
              << "\ntime = " << time.count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Also I am not a mathmaticain but the optimal way do this would be a way of represnting it as a sequence which can be computed in o(1) rather than as a loop but I aren't sure whether that is possible.